# How can I fix the error on this Python code?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this superclass:

import wx

```
class Plugin(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.colorOver = ((89,89,89))
        self.colorLeave = ((110,110,110))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self.colorLeave)
        self.SetForegroundColour(self.colorLeave)
        self.name = "plugin"

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, self.getName(), style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onMouseOver)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.onMouseLeave)

    def onMouseOver(self, event):
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self.colorOver)
        self.Refresh()

    def onMouseLeave(self, event):
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self.colorLeave)
        self.Refresh()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()
        app.Destroy()

    def getName(self):
        return self.name
```

and this subclass:

```
import plugin
import wx

class noisePlugin(plugin.Plugin):
    self.name = "noise"
```

and it gives me this error compiling the subclass:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\André Ferreira\Desktop\Tese\Código Python\SoundLog\Plugins\noisePlugin.py", line 4, in <module>
    class noisePlugin(plugin.Plugin):
  File "C:\Users\André Ferreira\Desktop\Tese\Código Python\SoundLog\Plugins\noisePlugin.py", line 5, in noisePlugin
    self.name = "noise"
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

What can I do to fix this error?
I want getName() method to return the name of the instanciated class!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the subclass

```
class noisePlugin(plugin.Plugin):
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        plugin.Plugin.__init__(self, *a, **k)
        self.name = "noise"
```

Whenever you want to use `self.`something you have to be **within a method**, not at class level outside of methods!

Comment: @aF, glad to have been of help!-)

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this works?

```
class noisePlugin(plugin.Plugin):
    self.name = "noise"
```

Why didn't you copy the

```
class Plugin(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
```

That comes before `self.name=`?

Answer (score 0):

For the pattern you seem to be trying for (where the name is associated more with the class than with the instance), this is often a better idiom to follow:

```
class A(object):
    name = 'parent'

    def __init__(self, ...):
       ... etc

class B(A):
    name = 'child'

    def __init__(self, ...):
        A.__init__(self, ...)
        ... etc
```

Even though the name attribute is stored on the class rather than the instance, you can access it using `self.name` in all the instances.  Generally if you find yourself assigning a static (unchanging) attribute that is the same in all instances of a given class you should just use a static class attribute like this.

On a slightly different topic, were you aware that all wxPython widgets already have a name attribute, which can be assigned using the `name` keyword argument at initialization time, and accessed using either `GetName()` or (in recent versions of wxPython) the property `Name`?  If you don't assign it, it will default to some fairly generic class-specific value (like `"text"` or `"textctrl"` for wx.TextCtrl).  Depending on what you're trying to do, maybe you can just use it instead of your own `name` and `getName()`.  wxPython itself does not make any use of this value, as it's intended for you the programmer to use as you see fit.